# Mpeg-2 patents in Malaysia and Philippines

Tags: expiration, mpeg-2

Mpeg-2 patents have now expired in most countries at the beginning of 2018. However, at least Malaysia and Philippines still have active mpeg-2 patents.

So does anyone know when mpeg-2 patents expire in Malaysia and Philippines ?

Addition: I've written an mpeg-2 decoder and wondering when I can give it away free.

Comment: That's a pretty big question. There is no "the mpeg-2" patent which we could just look up. There might be a more or less complete list of relevant patents somewhere because it's such a big standard, but per se, the question would require researching in every country any possibly relevant patent.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Comment: If you want to test something, it's better to do it in the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/295232).

Comment: @Glorfindel use the rollback function in edit mode, review doesn't show the edit history so it's hard to check your edit else. But you're right of course, I rolled it back and flagged for moderator attention in case this goes on.

Comment: AFAIK there is no rollback for suggested edits; all you can do is select another revision as starting point (which I did).

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia page for MPEG-2 contains a statement about Malaysia and the Philippines.

> As of April 1 2019, only Malaysia and the Philippines still have active patents covering MPEG-2. Patents in the rest of the world have expired, with the last US patent expiring February 23, 2018.[30]

I assume that is the basis for the question. The footnote [30] for the sentence
references a document -

> "MPEG-2 Attachment 1" (PDF). MPEG LA. Archived (PDF) from the original on 29 May 2019. Retrieved 29 May 2019.

I have a link to that reference below. It seems to be a list of MPEG-2 patents by patent owner. The first page lists patent numbers in the two countries you asked about. Assuming this is authoritative, you could look up those patents and get an answer.

> July 1, 2019 MPEG-2 Attachment 1 Page 1 of 24

- GE Technology Development, Inc. MY 118172-A - Expires September 30,
  2019 MY 1289941 MY 141626-A PH 1-1993-47458 - Expires July 17, 2019
- Sony Corporation MY 118444
- Thomson Licensing MY 118734-A PH    1-1995-50216

https://www.mpegla.com/wp-content/uploads/m2-att1.pdf